# Jekyll – Setting a site wide default layout

Tags: ruby, jekyll, config

I'm trying to set a site wide layout (a header and footer) to my Jekyll project to my config.yml file to no success. I've looked through the documentation and followed what it has said. Why is this not working?

**Config.yml**

```
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
    permalink: /:name

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

Comment: Can you please link to a GitHub repo that shows the problem? Can you please be more specific than saying "why is this not working"? What did you expect this code to do? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just having a file named "default"[.html/.md] in the `_layouts` folder should act as the site wide default layout page. Then the other **layout** files, if you have any, can inherit the default layout by adding the `layout` yaml front matter to them.

`default.html` in `_layouts`

```
<!-- default.html -->
{% include header.html %}

{{ content }}

{% include footer.html %}
```

other layout templates in `_layouts`:

```
<!-- _ projects_layout -->
---
layout: default
---
```